# Laravel RESTful routing

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-4

Consider the following 3 lines of code in a routes file:

```php
Route::pattern('token', '[0-9a-z]+');

Route::get('user/reset/{token}', 'UserController@getReset');

Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

Are the pattern and get routes serving any purpose in this example? As I understand it, the RESTful controller route at the bottom will match any user/reset/{target} URL to the UserController getReset action, regardless of any token pattern supplied.

Is it possible to use a regex constraint on a route like this, where there is also a "catch-all" controller route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra routes aren't needed in this example.

Right now, all the /user/reset requests are going to getReset. You could either send the constrained route to a different method, or neater, perform the validation in the controller to match the token and throw an exception if it doesn't match your constraints (or pass them off to your catch all idea).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Beech, for confirming my thinking & suggesting these alternatives.